# Firefox does not properly handle try/catch blocks in window.onerror

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

It seems that Firefox treats any error that occurs in the window.onerror event handler as a fatal exception even if the exception is caught. The following code sample works as expected in IE, Chrome, and Safari. In Firefox, the call to the non-existent abc() method halts the execution immediately instead of executing the catch block and the remainder of the onerror handler.

Is this expected behavior in Firefox or am I doing something wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            window.onerror = function() {
                console.log('begin onerror');

                try {
                    abc(); // create a runtime error by calling a method that doesn't exist
                } catch(e) { 
                    console.log('catch block'); 
                }

                console.log('end onerror');
            };

            $('#btn').click(function() {
                xyz(); // create a runtime error by calling a method that doesn't exist
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" name="frmEdit">
        <input type="button" value="Test" id="btn" name="btn" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This smells like a bug around logic which likely exists to prevent infinite recursive loops in the onError handler. Normally, try...catch takes precedence over the onError handler, but _in_ the onError handler it appears as though this precedence is not maintained.

Comment: This is my suspicion as well. I will probably end up filing a bug report. I figured I would get a more immediate response here first though.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the onError function, you will see that execution starts at onError and not at the xyz call. You will probably see this issue any time the call stack starts at onError. The only way around it to change the execution stack, such as with setTimeout(abc, 0)...but that is ugly.

Comment: link to the bug filed: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=704259

Comment: Based on Nickolay's updated test case, I filed a bug report with the jQuery team as well. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10904

Answer (score 1):

As [this testcase](https://bug704259.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=577102) demonstrates, it's related to jQuery.

Replacing the jQuery dependency with the minimal code necessary to trigger this behavior will either explain this or make this easier to debug and fix on the Firefox side.

[edit] Thanks to jrotello, dmethvin, and Firefox developers, the [underlying issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=704259) should be fixed in Firefox 14 (you can test it before it's released using http://nightly.mozilla.org/)

Comment: This definitely seems to point to jQuery. I didn't even think to try to wire the click event differently.